# Python script not working in linux

Tags: python, linux

I have this python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime, os
from time import gmtime, strftime

to_backup = "/home/vmware/tobackup"
var1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%p')
for f in os.listdir(to_backup):
    if(os.path.isfile(f)):
        print f + " is a file"
    if(os.path.isdir(f)):
        print f + " is a directory"
```

It is giving me empty ouput. i don't know where is the problem

OUTPUT FOR dr jimbob answer

```
total 36
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vmware vmware  440 May  5 07:41 back.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vmware vmware 2624 May  4 20:35 backup.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 vmware vmware 4096 Jun 22  2010 Desktop
drwxrwxr-x 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:51 destination
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 May  4 18:49 public_html
drwxrwxr-x 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  1 07:47 python
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vmware vmware  560 May  1 13:20 regex.py
drwxrwxrwx 7 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:50 tobackup
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:50 five
drwxrwxrwx 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:50 four
drwxrwxrwx 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:50 one
drwxrwxrwx 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:50 three
drwxrwxrwx 2 vmware vmware 4096 May  5 03:50 two
```

Comment: What does `os.listdir(to_backup)` give you? Can you manually verify through the shell that there are files in that directory?

Comment: the files are there and i tried the listdir command and it again shows empty

Comment: Call your script (let's say it is called lister.py) with python -v lister.py and post output please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok you have permission, but you aren't in the right directory when you list through the files.  list_dir gives you a list of dirs/files without their path, and `os.path.isfile('one')` and `os.path.isdir('one')` will check whether the directory 'one' exists in the current directory (wherever you launched the script from, unless you explicitly changed directory with `os.chdir` or included the path, e.g., `os.path.isdir('/home/vmware/tobackup/one')`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime, os
from time import gmtime, strftime
import subprocess

to_backup = "/home/vmware/tobackup"
var1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%p')

os.chdir(to_backup)
# os.listdir(to_backup) = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
for f in os.listdir(to_backup):
    if(os.path.isfile(f)):
        print f + " is a file"
    if(os.path.isdir(f)):
        print f + " is a directory"
```

or

```
to_backup = "/home/vmware/tobackup"
var1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%p')
# os.listdir(to_backup) = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
for f in os.listdir(to_backup):
    if(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(to_backup,f))):
        print f + " is a file"
    if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(to_backup,f))):
        print f + " is a directory"
```

or with `walk` (but not actually walking through subdirs).

```
to_backup = "/home/vmware/tobackup"
var1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%p')

root, dirs, files in os.walk(to_backup).next()
for file in files:
    print f + " is a file in " + root
for dir in dirs:
    print f + " is a directory"
```

EDIT:  To be even clearer, the mistake with your original script is you have a file structure like:

```
/home/user/bin/your_script.py
/home/vmware/tobackup/
/home/vmware/tobackup/one
/home/vmware/tobackup/two
...
```

When you go to /home/user/bin to run your script (e.g., `python your_script.py`), `os.listdir('/home/vmware/tobackup')` gives you a list of file and dir names in /home/vmware/tobackup, that is `['one','two', ...]`.  However, when you do `os.path.isfile('one')` from the directory /home/user/bin, you check to see if `/home/user/bin/one` is a file, not whether /home/vmware/tobackup/one is a file.  Since `/home/user/bin/one` doesn't exist, you get no output.

Comment: The above script worked . why is that . i have added the output in questions

Comment: Well, I explicitly ran commands to list the directories.  What you need to do (now that we've checked that you have permissions and files/dirs are there), is go to that directory.  (E.g., `os.chdir(to_backup)`).  Let say you are running the script from directory '~/bin/', and os.list_dir(to_backup) = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'].  You then check to see if os.path.isfile('one') is a file or dir in the current directory (which it isn't as `~/bin/one` doesn't exist).  A much better solution would be to use `os.walk`.  http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: @Mahakaal: When your script gets `os.listdir`, you have a list `['one', 'two', ...]`.  Then `os.path.isfile('one')` run from /home/vmware it checks to see if /home/vmware/one is a file (which it isn't; it doesn't exist).  You'd like it to check to see if `/home/vmware/tobackup/one` is a file.  To do that, you either have to change you current directory to `/home/vmware/tobackup` (as shown in my first solution with `os.chdir` or make sure you don't check for f (which is just 'one', 'two', but check for '/home/vmware/tobackup/one' with os.path.join(to_backup, f) as the 2nd soln.

Comment: Thanks buddy that was great detail , ur other solutions worked very well. i really appreciate ur effort on this

Answer (score 4):

It works on my machine (ubuntu 10.10)
Maybe /home/vmware/tobackup is empty or you have no permissions to read it.

Comment: i have all the permissions ls command is working but not python commands

Comment: 'pdb' is your friend - instead of *guessing* the error problem: debug it using *pdb*

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir(dir_name)` returns filenames *relative to the named directory*. To use those in other commands, you need to either prepend the directory name (via `f = os.path.join(to_backup, f)` at the start of the loop body) or else change the working directory to the backup directory before starting the loop.

These are the first two alternatives shown in dr jimbob's answer.